# docker-compose returns error when trying to start on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I want to deploy my server to an AWS EC2 instance. When I enter 'sudo docker-compose up' in the ssh console, I get the following error:

> ERROR: for nginx  Cannot start service nginx: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:430: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\"/home/ubuntu/site/nginx/default.conf\\" to rootfs \\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b24f64910c6ab7727a4cb08afac0d034bb759baa4bfd605466ca760359f411c2/merged\\" at \\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b24f64910c6ab7727a4cb08afac0d034bb759baa4bfd605466ca760359f411c2/merged/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf\\" caused \\"not a directory\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'

networks:
    SRVR:

services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:stable-alpine
        container_name: SRVR_nginx
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        volumes:
            - ./code:/code
            - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
            - ./nginx/logs:/var/log/nginx
        depends_on:
            - php
        networks:
            - SRVR

    php:
        build: ./php
        container_name: SRVR_php
        volumes:
            - ./code:/code
        ports:
            - "9000:9000"
        networks:
            - SRVR
```

The same docker-compose.yml is working fine on my local compuer which runs Ubuntu OS. The EC2 instance also runs Ubuntu OS.

Comment: Try to COPY your files in the Dockerfile for production builds. In our production docker-compose regime, we use the Dockerfile to COPY the files we need and locally we use volume syncs like you are doing above

Comment: The error message suggests `./nginx/default.conf` on the EC2 instance doesn't exist.  Does it?

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for the clue. Turns out for some reason `./nginx/default.conf` is being created as a folder, instead of a file. I'm going to answer my own question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is with `./nginx/default.conf`. docker recognises that as a folder and you have `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` being a file.

Answer (score 1):

I was too hasty to ask. Here's what's going on. The Nginx container requires the 'default.conf' file to be created manually. If it's not, bringing nginx server up creates a folder called 'default.conf'. Once I've manually copied my original 'default.conf' file to the appropriate location, everything seems to be working fine.